# Why is it showing errors in my smart contract (Solidity)?

Tags: solidity, ether, myetherwallet

Actually, I wrote the code in multiple files, but since I need to Verify and deploy the code . But now it is showing way too many warning then compilation failed. I put the code below with error messages in comments, can you guys please help me with the warning

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
///Implements EIP20 token standard: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;


import "./erc20Interface.sol";

contract ERC20Token is ERC20Interface {

    uint256 constant private MAX_UINT256 = 2**256 - 1;
    mapping (address => uint256) public balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowed;

    uint256 public totSupply;           // Total number of tokens
    string public name;                   // Descriptive name (i.e. For Dummies Sample Token)
    uint8 public decimals;                // How many decimals to use when displaying amounts
    string public symbol;                 // Short identifier for token (i.e. FDT)

    // Create the new token and assign initial values, including initial amount
    constructor(
        uint256 _initialAmount,
        string memory _tokenName,
        uint8 _decimalUnits,
        string memory _tokenSymbol
    ) public {
        balances[msg.sender] = _initialAmount;               // The creator owns all initial tokens
        totSupply = _initialAmount;                        // Update total token supply
        name = _tokenName;                                   // Store the token name (used for display only)
        decimals = _decimalUnits;                            // Store the number of decimals (used for display only)
        symbol = _tokenSymbol;                               // Store the token symbol (used for display only)
    }

    // Transfer tokens from msg.sender to a specified address
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value,"Insufficient funds for transfer source.");
        balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value); //solhint-disable-line indent, no-unused-vars
        return true;
    }

    // Transfer tokens from one specified address to another specified address
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        uint256 allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];
        require(balances[_from] >= _value && allowance >= _value,"Insufficient allowed funds for transfer source.");
        balances[_to] += _value;
        balances[_from] -= _value;
        if (allowance < MAX_UINT256) {
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        }
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value); //solhint-disable-line indent, no-unused-vars
        return true;
    }

    // Return the current balance (in tokens) of a specified address
    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    // Set
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value); //solhint-disable-line indent, no-unused-vars
        return true;
    }

    // Return the allowance
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    // Return the total number of tokens in circulation
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256 totSupp) {
        return totSupply;
    }
}
```

the compiling warning:

```
C:\Users\m_swe\project\supplychain>truffle deploy --reset

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\SupplyChain.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\basicMath.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\erc20Interface.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\erc20Token.sol

> Compilation warnings encountered:

    Warning: This declaration shadows an existing declaration.
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Token.sol:47:9:
   |
47 |         uint256 allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: The shadowed declaration is here:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Token.sol:71:5:
   |
71 |     function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
   |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

,Warning: Visibility for constructor is ignored. If you want the contract to be non-deployable, making it "abstract" is sufficient.
 --> project:/contracts/Migrations.sol:8:3:
  |
8 |   constructor() public {
  |   ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

,Warning: Visibility for constructor is ignored. If you want the contract to be non-deployable, making it "abstract" is sufficient.
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Token.sol:23:5:
   |
23 |     constructor(
   |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).


DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Token.sol:17:5:
   |
17 |     uint256 public totSupply;           // Total number of tokens
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: The previous declaration is here:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:11:5:
   |
11 |     uint256 public totSupply;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,TypeError: Contract "ERC20Interface" should be marked as abstract.
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:10:1:
   |
10 | contract ERC20Interface {
   | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Missing implementation:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:15:5:
   |
15 |     function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: Missing implementation:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:17:5:
   |
17 |     function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: Missing implementation:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:14:5:
   |
14 |     function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: Missing implementation:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:13:5:
   |
13 |     function totalSupply() public view returns (uint);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: Missing implementation:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:16:5:
   |
16 |     function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: Missing implementation:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:18:5:
   |
18 |     function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,TypeError: Overriding function is missing "override" specifier.
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Token.sol:37:5:
   |
37 |     function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
   |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Overridden function is here:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:16:5:
   |
16 |     function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,TypeError: Trying to override non-virtual function. Did you forget to add "virtual"?
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:16:5:
   |
16 |     function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: Overriding function is here:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Token.sol:37:5:
   |
37 |     function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
   |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

,TypeError: Overriding function is missing "override" specifier.
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Token.sol:46:5:
   |
46 |     function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
   |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Overridden function is here:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:18:5:
   |
18 |     function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,TypeError: Trying to override non-virtual function. Did you forget to add "virtual"?
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:18:5:
   |
18 |     function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: Overriding function is here:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Token.sol:46:5:
   |
46 |     function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
   |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

,TypeError: Overriding function is missing "override" specifier.
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Token.sol:59:5:
   |
59 |     function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
   |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Overridden function is here:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:14:5:
   |
14 |     function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,TypeError: Trying to override non-virtual function. Did you forget to add "virtual"?
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:14:5:
   |
14 |     function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: Overriding function is here:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Token.sol:59:5:
   |
59 |     function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
   |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

,TypeError: Overriding function is missing "override" specifier.
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Token.sol:64:5:
   |
64 |     function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
   |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Overridden function is here:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:17:5:
   |
17 |     function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,TypeError: Trying to override non-virtual function. Did you forget to add "virtual"?
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:17:5:
   |
17 |     function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: Overriding function is here:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Token.sol:64:5:
   |
64 |     function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
   |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

,TypeError: Overriding function is missing "override" specifier.
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Token.sol:71:5:
   |
71 |     function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
   |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Overridden function is here:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:15:5:
   |
15 |     function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,TypeError: Trying to override non-virtual function. Did you forget to add "virtual"?
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:15:5:
   |
15 |     function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: Overriding function is here:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Token.sol:71:5:
   |
71 |     function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
   |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

,TypeError: Overriding function is missing "override" specifier.
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Token.sol:76:5:
   |
76 |     function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256 totSupp) {
   |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Overridden function is here:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:13:5:
   |
13 |     function totalSupply() public view returns (uint);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,TypeError: Trying to override non-virtual function. Did you forget to add "virtual"?
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:13:5:
   |
13 |     function totalSupply() public view returns (uint);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: Overriding function is here:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Token.sol:76:5:
   |
76 |     function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256 totSupp) {
   |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

,TypeError: Overriding public state variable is missing "override" specifier.
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Token.sol:17:5:
   |
17 |     uint256 public totSupply;           // Total number of tokens
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: Overridden public state variable is here:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:11:5:
   |
11 |     uint256 public totSupply;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,TypeError: Cannot override public state variable.
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:11:5:
   |
11 |     uint256 public totSupply;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: Overriding public state variable is here:
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Token.sol:17:5:
   |
17 |     uint256 public totSupply;           // Total number of tokens
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,TypeError: "now" has been deprecated. Use "block.timestamp" instead.
  --> project:/contracts/SupplyChain.sol:69:55:
   |
69 |             products[productId].mfgTimeStamp = uint32(now);
   |                                                       ^^^

,TypeError: "now" has been deprecated. Use "block.timestamp" instead.
   --> project:/contracts/SupplyChain.sol:102:60:
    |
102 |             ownerships[ownership_id].trxTimeStamp = uint32(now);
    |                                                            ^^^

,TypeError: "now" has been deprecated. Use "block.timestamp" instead.
   --> project:/contracts/SupplyChain.sol:113:60:
    |
113 |             ownerships[ownership_id].trxTimeStamp = uint32(now);
    |                                                            ^^^

,TypeError: "now" has been deprecated. Use "block.timestamp" instead.
   --> project:/contracts/SupplyChain.sol:124:60:
    |
124 |             ownerships[ownership_id].trxTimeStamp = uint32(now);
    |                                                            ^^^

,TypeError: Functions without implementation must be marked virtual.
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:13:5:
   |
13 |     function totalSupply() public view returns (uint);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,TypeError: Functions without implementation must be marked virtual.
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:14:5:
   |
14 |     function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,TypeError: Functions without implementation must be marked virtual.
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:15:5:
   |
15 |     function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,TypeError: Functions without implementation must be marked virtual.
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:16:5:
   |
16 |     function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,TypeError: Functions without implementation must be marked virtual.
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:17:5:
   |
17 |     function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,TypeError: Functions without implementation must be marked virtual.
  --> project:/contracts/erc20Interface.sol:18:5:
   |
18 |     function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.4.17 (core: 5.4.17)
Node v16.13.0
```

Answer (score 0):

- Most of these errors comes that you didn't set the `override` modifier. Standards are described as an interface, and inheriting them allows you to ensure you implement all and every mandatory methods, *with the correct function signature/names* -> add `override` to those functions and implement the ones that are missing
- You `allowance` method has the same name as your `allowance` mapping, hence the shadowing warning (change the variable name)
- The use of the [global variable](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties) `now` is deprecated, replace `now` by `block.timestamp`